# Please explain this notation MW around 9 MDa

Tags: enzymes, 3d-structure

I am a computational science student and was reading about the structure of Pyruvate dehydrogenase (PDH).

[link to article](http://www.mitosciences.com/pyruvate_dehydrogenase.html)

The article mentions "PDH is a large complex (**MW around 9 MDa**) consisting of multiple copies of three enzymes."

What does **MW around 9 MDa** denote ?

I am not a regular student of biology but rather an engineering student so please try to provide simple explanations.

Comment: MW is Molecular Weight, or the mass of 1 mole of the protein. 9 MDa is 9 million Daltons, and 1 Dalton is 1 gram per mole. So a mole of PDH is about 9 million grams.

Comment: One Dalton = 1.66×10⁻²⁷ kg and one mole = 6.023 10²³ molecules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The molecular weight of PDH enzyme is approximately 9$\times$10$^6$ gm/mol**

The Dalton (or atomic mass unit (amu) ) is a unit of mass defined as 1/12 weight of carbon-12 atom in  ground state.
1 Da  = 1/12 m(12C)

The number of atoms in 1 mole is Avogadro's number (6.023 x 10^23) so weight of 1 carbon atom is   =   (12/ 6.023 x 10^23 ) g

This means 1Da (1 amu)  = 1/12 x (12/ 6.023 x 10^23 ) g = 1/ 6.023 x 10^23 g  which is g/mole

(1 MOLE = 6.023 x 10^23 )

=> 1 Da = 1g/mole